# Internal Programmable ROM of CP2102 (USB to UART)

Tags: usb, uart

I am using CP2102 device (USB to UART) in my project. It has internal programmable ROM t0 configure product ID. I tried in there tool via USB and it works. 
Now, I want to programming the ROM via my MCU. Has anyone tried this?

Thanks and regards,

Comment: I assume your micro is connected to the UART side. The CP2102 datasheet says nothing about programming the EEPROM from the UART side. I don't expect it to be possible since the UART is transferring data transparently to the USB side and you'd need some escape process that could not happen in normal data.

Comment: I've been using CP2102's for years & I've never seen any way to do that. The functionality exposed to your micro is just a simple UART interface - there's no way to talk to the internals of the device from that end.